# Angularjs filter complex JSON by array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, json, filter

I'm having a dropdown list with multiselect option. I want to filter out data from a complex JSON based on that array.

Selected options forms a array of data like:

```
$scope.myval=["Adyar","Paris","central"];
```

My JSON :

```
$scope.myTest={     
    "buslist":
        {
        "code":"1",
        "message":"Success",
        "fromStationCode":"71",
        "searchResult":[        {
        "arrivalTime":"17:00:00",
        "availableSeats":"42",
        "boardingPointDetails":[{
        "code":"1631",
        "name":"Koyambedu",
        "time":"09:30:00"
        },
        {
        "code":"961296",
        "name":"Paris",
        "time":"09:45:00"
        }
        ]
        ]
        },

         {
        "arrivalTime":"18:00:00",
        "availableSeats":"32",
        "boardingPointDetails":[{
        "code":"2084",
        "name":"Adyar",
        "time":"09:30:00"
        },
        {
        "code":"961296",
        "name":"Madurai",
        "time":"09:45:00"
        }
        ]
        ]
        }
        }
        ...
    };
```

My HTML templating is:

```
                <tbody ng-repeat=" i in myTest.buslist.searchResult" >
                <tr>
                    <td>{{i.arrivalTime}}</td>
                    <td>{{i.availableSeats}}</td>

                    <td>
                    <p ng-repeat="m in i.boardingPointDetails">{{m.name}}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

I want to filter my data based on selected values. I had tried something like this :

```
$scope.matched = $scope.myTest.buslist.searchResult.boardingPointDetails.name.indexOf(data);
```

i.e:selected options must match "name" field in "boardingPointDetails"  but it fails. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since `$scope.myTest.buslist.searchResult.boardingPointDetails` is an array 
`$scope.myTest.buslist.searchResult.boardingPointDetails.name` is not valid.

You need to use an Array function to get the correct result:

```
$scope.matched = $scope.myTest.buslist.searchResult.boardingPointDetails.filter(function(el) {
   return el.name === data;
}).length > 0;
```

---

EDIT:

Due to your comments I understand you want to get the `boardPointDetails` that has the same `name` property as one of the `data` options. Where `data` is an Array of strings.

This will do the job:

```
$scope.matched = $scope.myTest.buslist.searchResult.boardingPointDetails.filter(function(el) {
   return data.indexOf(el.name) === 1;
});
```

Comment: what does `data` contain? what is it's structure?

Comment: data is nothing but selected options. It is in array format.$scope.myval=["Adyar","Paris","central"];

Comment: so data is an Array of strings. What is the condition? Do all those values need to be in `boardingPointDetails`? Or just one of them?

Comment: boardingPointDetails that matches any one of the value in array should be displayed as output.

Comment: added an edit to my answer. note that `$scope.matched` will hold the whole object that matches. In your example it will be: `{
        "code":"961296",
        "name":"Paris",
        "time":"09:45:00"
        }`

Comment: try googling "angular filter", although you can simply use the `matched` scoped variable wherever this scope is available. Anyway, this is subject to a separate question